# opencv stereobm, is it really based on SAD cost function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to enhance the stereobm (Opencv stereo block matching).
they claim that this algorithm uses the SAD cost_function method. (SAD Sum of Aboslue Differences).

But in the code 
they have computed the SAD  this way:

```
        for( y = -dy0; y < height + dy1; y++, cbuf += ndisp, cbuf_sub += ndisp,
         hsad += ndisp, lptr += sstep, lptr_sub += sstep, rptr += sstep )
    {
        int lval = lptr[0];
        for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
        {
            int diff = std::abs(lval - rptr[d]);
            cbuf[d] = (uchar)diff;
            hsad[d] = hsad[d] + diff - cbuf_sub[d];
        }
        htext[y] += tab[lval] - tab[lptr_sub[0]];
    }
......
sad[d] = (int)(hsad0[d-ndisp*dy0]*(wsz2 + 2 - dy0));

//   *******************************
Instead of 
//....
hsad[d] = hsad[d] + diff ;  
// .....
sad[d] =  hsad[d]
```

So,  why they did a multiplication with *(wsz2 + 2 - dy0)) ?

and why they substract cbuf_sub[d]   from hsad[d]    in   ( hsad[d] = hsad[d] + diff - cbuf_sub[d];)

Comment: what's the value of `wsz2`? I guess it's some kind of normalization term?

Comment: wsz2  is the half of the windows size   and dy0 comes from the region of interest dy0= roi.y;

Answer (score 5):

Yes, OpenCV StereoBM is really based on SAD.

When you slide the sliding window in the y direction by one row, you do not have to recalculate the SAD for the whole window. Instead, you add the SAD of the new row to the SAD of the window. Also, you subtract from it the SAD of the row that is no longer in the window.

In other words, once you have the initial window's SAD, you start sliding the window and adding to the SAD only the part that is new to the window, and subtracting the part that is not in the window anymore, as the window has already passed it.

This is exactly what is done in OpenCV code:

```
hsad[d] = hsad[d] + diff - cbuf_sub[d];
...
int currsad = sad[d] + hsad[d] - hsad_sub[d];
```

You were confused by the sad[] initialization code that takes care of the border case:

```
    // initialize sums
    for( d = 0; d < ndisp; d++ )
        sad[d] = (int)(hsad0[d-ndisp*dy0]*(wsz2 + 2 - dy0));
```

This is how the first half of the first window is initialized. It means that hsad values for rows before the first row have the same value as the hsad for the first row. Right after this code comes the code to initialize the other half of the window, where hsad values are already from valid rows.